# Selenium java window().fullscreen() goes back to normal size

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Selenium java window().fullscreen() goes back to normal size.

```
driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
```

Full scrren works on Chrome, but it immediately goes back to normal size on first page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page reloads after using `driver.manage().window().fullscreen();` browser window will return to its normal size. If you want to keep the browser window in full-screen mode after the page is reloaded, you will need to include the "fullscreen()" method in your code again after the page reloads.

Alternatively, you can use 'setSize()' method to set the window size accordingly or 'maximize()' method to maximize browser window and these changes persist even after page reload.

Use 'setSize()' as below:

`driver.manage().window().setSize(height, width);` where height and width, you can use your screen height and width to set the browser window to match that.

Use 'maximize()' method as below:

`driver.manage().window().maximize();`

Comment: what is the reason why it goes back to normal size after reload? thanks.

Comment: @eastwater Becuase, ```driver.manage().window().fullscreen();``` sets the current instance of the window to full screen mode. But, reloading the page creates new instance of the window. So, browser, resets the view to default size of the window.

Comment: I see. What is needed is the fullscreen for the browser instance, not window fullscreen. e.g.,  driver.fullscreen(). thanks.

Comment: By window, I mean browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You Can also use Dimension Class to set the browser Size.

Dimension size=new Dimension();

//for current size of the browser
int hight=size.gethight();

int width=size.getwidth();

Dimension sz=new Dimension(1000,900);

sz.manage().window.setSize(sz);

///You can also use the JavaScript Engine to find the height and width of the browser.

Ex-
var w =window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;